# My old java program suddenly cannot access folder in win 10

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an old program (3 months ago) that usually running well in my windows 10 laptop. This program is to access main\resources folder under my eclipse project. So I create a Test.java to test whats going on.

```
public class Test {
    private static String rootPath = "D:\\Projects\\Eclipse Projects\\com.litaal.calendar\\src\\main\\resources\\";
    private static String[] pairs = { "AUDUSD" };
    private static String[] times = { "H1" };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (String pair : Arrays.asList(pairs)) {
            for (String tf : Arrays.asList(times)) {
                String path = rootPath + pair + "\\" + tf;
                System.out.println(path);
                File folder = new File(path);
                if (folder.isDirectory()) {
                    System.out.println("ITS A FOLDER");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("ITS NOT A FOLDER");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It used to be able to access main\resources folder and my target folder does exists (see below picture)

[image]

I even change the Security of main\resources folder to enable every user got a full access, and even running my eclipse as an administrator, but it seems my Java code cannot have access to that folder. It keeps returned ITS NOT A FOLDER. Can anybody help?

Comment: What does this line of your code print? `System.out.println(path);`

Comment: If you are using at least Java 7, consider using [NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/index.html)

Comment: could you run the following code and show the output: `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());` (Just to make sure your path is correct. On the side-bar of eclipse, it looks like `com-litaal-calendar`, however your path includes `com.litaal.calendar` so I wonder whether the path is correct)

Comment: What folder is it claiming isn't one?